# How do I change \footnote font size in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, fontsize

I tried all methods from this question: [How to change font family in footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/how-to-change-font-family-in-footnote)
and none of them work for me...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command setting the desired size is `\footnotesize`. It can be used also outside footnotes, for text matching the size of footnotes. If that text should be treated different, it should not use `\footnotesize`, logically. So let's rely on consistent use.

The command `\footnotesize` does some more than changing the font size, it adjusts further śpace values such as in lists and around math formulas.

As default, beamer loads `size11.clo`, there `\footnotesize` is defined as:

```
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
```

Just to let you know what's the orignal. You could redefine `\footnotesize`. You could even to that using the original, for keeping the spacing values:

```
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{\oldfootnotesize\tiny}
```

Instead of the simple example `\tiny` you could use an arbitrary size by `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`.

Answer (score 45):

The "*official*" method to change the \footnote font size is a call to `\setbeamerfont` applied to the `footnote` beamer font.

Example:

```
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
```

Default is:

```
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\footnotesize}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Text \footnote{First footnote}

  \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
  Text \footnote{Second footnote}

  \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\footnotesize}
  Text \footnote{Third footnote}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if `french` option of `babel` is used.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé With `french` option of `babel`, `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}...` and `\setbeamerfont{footnote}...`  don't work. It's like a bug in `babel-french`...

Comment: @DenisBitouzé You may use `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} ` as a workaround...

Comment: `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}` is indeed only a workaround: you loose the nice way French footnotes are displayed. Bug reported to `babel-french`'s author.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to change the footnote text size for a single footnote, as one occasionally has to do when citing long URLs, the `graphicx` package loaded with

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

provides the `\scalebox{<scale>}{<text>}` command, where `<scale>` denotes the ratio of the new size to the original size. For example:

```
The StackExchange website provides an almost infinite amount of \LaTeX\ wisdom!%
\footnote{\scalebox{0.8}{%
  \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21741/how-do-i-change-footnote-font-size-in-beamer-presentation}%
}}
```

The footnote in this example would be set to 80% of the normal size.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to change the numbers in before the footnotes text? I use your method, but the number 1, 2, 3 before footnotes are still a little bit big.