# Changing the appearance of citations with biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using biblatex to add references in slides made with beamer. In following slide I need to make following changes:

1. Remove black line that separates the contents of slide from the ref.
2. Reduce font size of reference.
3. Is is to possible to specify the color in which one wants the ref to appear.

[image]

Following is the code for the love slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{\color{blue}{Dummy Slide \footfullcite{dumref}}}}
\begin{center}
\framebox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}]
\draw [dashed] (1,12) -- (11,12);
\node[above] at (4,11) {1}; \node[above] at (8,11) {true};
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which colour do you refer to exactly in point 3? The colour of the footnote marker, or the text in the footnote?

Comment: @ moewe....its the text color that I would like to change But I think it will be interesting to see how one can control footnote color as well.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: See also [How to change the color of bibitems?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225218/35864)

Answer (score 1):

The footnote rule can be removed with

```
\def\footnoterule{}
```

You can change the font size in footnotes with

```
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\normalsize}
```

see [How do I change \footnote font size in beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21741/35864).

Three parts of the citation are coloured: name, title and remaining information. The colour can be set independently for all the parts.

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=blue}
```

[image: colourful example]

The colour of the footnote marker can be set with

```
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=.}
```

see [Making footnote marks in beamer use the surrounding color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154819/35864). Here it is set to adapt to the surrounding text colour, but you can also choose `\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=pink}` or any other color.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny} but the issue is that I don't have enough space left on my slide for display of complete reference (even with tiny font size). Should I change citation style in this case

Comment: @NAASI I would not ever make something `\tiny` in beamer, after all people are supposed to read the what you have on your frames, aren't they? If the frame doesn't have enough space left, try and split the content overs several frames. Or use another citation/bibliography style. If you want to have a bibliography at the end, you can probably get away with something author-year-like.

Comment: @NAASI You could also suppress certain fields in the footnote with `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\clearfield`: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{doi}}` gets rid of the DOI.