# LuaLaTex - problems with german characters

Tags: symbols, german, quotation

I switched from LaTex to LuaLaTex. This is my basic preamble:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

For some reason, with LuaLaTex charakters like `ß` are displayed as `SS`and the german glyphs / quotation marks are displayed wrong. I still don't exactly know how to print these symbols. Sometimes I stumbled over "' or '' (cant even display these symbols correctly in this editor). With LaTex the notation `,, / ''` did work so far, but it does not with LuaLaTex.

Is there some recommenced general robust way to do this, that works with LaTex and LuaLaTex without fiddeling around and will not create other side-effects?

Comment: `inputenc` and `fontenc` shouldn't be used in LuaTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: Could you explain why this is not nescessary any more?

Comment: don't use lmodern either.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470987/2388 why fontenc can be a problem with luatex.

Comment: Because these packages are work-arounds to have an 8-bit engine, like pdfTeX, understand multi-byte encodings, like utf8. XeTeX and LuaTeX are unicode aware engines, so these packages do nothing at best. At worst they make special characters not work, like what you're seeing. Removing those packages solves the issue for me.

Comment: If you change `\documentclass{article}`to the german version `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}` you get `GröSSe`.

Comment: The `babel` manual provides some explanations on how to use it with `lualatex` (sec. 1.4).

Comment: Ok, I did remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`, which did actually help. Do I have to be worried now aboud other things that could happen or just have to be solved by some workaround?

Comment: About the issue of getting the "correct" (i.e., "German"-style) quotation marks: I think this issue is separate from using pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. For maximum flexibility under either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I suggest you load the `csquotes` package with the option `german=quotes` (or, if you prefer, `german=guillemets`) and that you write `\enquote{Die Glocke}`, say, instead of using double back ticks and double apostrophes to encase the quoted material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments to you query have pointed out, one should *not* load the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages when using LuaLaTeX. Instead, get used to working with the `fontspec` package. Or, if your document has math-y parts, load the `unicode-math` package, which loads `fontspec` automatically.

Modifying the preamble as shown below lets you go back and forth between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. This may be the way to go for you until you've fully settled on LuaLaTeX.

[image]

The preceding screenshot is the result of compiling the following test document with LuaLaTeX. Observe the use of the `ß` character for both lowercase and uppercase. Compiling the same document under pdfLaTeX produces a nearly-identical result, except that it produces `SS` as the uppercase variant of `ß` for both the roman and the sans-serif font shape, and nothing at all for the monospaced font shape.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % no need to load 'amsfonts' explicitly
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
   \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
   \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
   \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
\else % pdflatex
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\begin{document}
äöü ÄÖÜ ß \MakeUppercase{ß}

\textsf{äöü ÄÖÜ ß \MakeUppercase{ß}}

\texttt{äöü ÄÖÜ ß \MakeUppercase{ß}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellend answer. Thanks!