# DeclareMathOperator does not respect math font

Tags: fonts, xetex, amsmath, math-operators, libertine

I use the Libertine font for text and math.
If I declare a new operator with `\DeclareMathOperator*`, the font used to typeset the operator is not Libertine.
For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\begin{equation*}
  x = y + \sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}} \beta_z
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  x = \argmin_{y \in Y} \bigg \{ f(y) + \frac{1}{g(y) - h(y)} \bigg\}
\end{equation*}
  
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: with Libertine]

Where `\argmin` is not in Libertine font.

I also noticed that commenting out `\usepackage{libertine}` gives me `\argmin` in the correct font but, of course, normal text is now not in Libertine any more:

[image: without Libertine]

**EDIT**: I just noticed this is a XeTeX-specific problem.
If I compile with `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`, the problem disappears.
In the project I am working on, however, I need XeTex, so just switching to `pdflatex` is not an option for now.

**EDIT2**: I tried the suggestions I received in an answer.

- Using `\usepackage[type1]{libertine}` and then `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` again gives me normal text in Computer Modern, and not in Libertine. The math operator, though, is now in Libertine.
- Using `\usepackage{libertinus}` before `\usepackage{amsmath}`, both with and without `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, gives a compilation error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \dddot already defined.`
- Inverting the order of package loads fixes the error. I mean that I load *first* `amsmath` and *then* `libertinus`, without loading `newtxmath`. In this case, I get the correct result for `\argmin`, but the rest of the math looks funny. See, for example, `\mathcal{Z}` or the curly braces in the screenshot below.
- Loading `amsmath` first, `libertinus` second, and `newtxmath` third, gives another compilation error: `! LaTeX Error: Command '\arrowvert' already defined.`.
- The last permutation, which is 1st `amsmath`, 2nd `newtxmath`, 3rd `libertinus`, gives one more compilation error: `! LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \not= already defined.`.

[image: With Libertinus]

**EDIT3**: Ok, I have a finally working version thanks to the answer below:

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

Comment: I get libertine. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Although it should not be necessary if your packages are properly installed, you can always redefine `\operator@font`.  With `unicode-math`, you should instead use `\setoperatorfont`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just ran a full system update (I am on Arch Linux) and, as far as I can tell, yes, the system is up-to-date. Running `xelatex --version` gives: `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)`. From the log file I also see I am using `Package: libertine 2019/02/27`, `newtxmath v1.553, 2018/05/15`, and `Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b`, which all look quite recent to me. Anything more specific I should be looking for?

Comment: I just managed to restrict the problem: compiling with `xelatex` gives the wrong font; compiling with `pdflatex` does not.

Comment: I get Latin/Computer Modern with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (on an up-to-date MikTeX). pdfLaTeX gives the expected result, though.

Comment: I edited to address the feedback and left the original answer below the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Ulrike Fischer posted a simpler and workaround than I came up with, but I’ll leave this up here in order to discuss some of the alternatives and problems you ran into.

The reason this happens when you compile with XeLaTeX but not PDFLaTeX is that the `libertine` package loads the OpenType version of the font on XeTeX.  There are clashes between how the packages you load define the operator font.  A mismatch between the font encoding and the font name causes XeTeX to load the default font instead.  It turns out that loading the packages in the right order fixes this.

However, there are a few alternatives to consider.  If you load `mathastext` after `libertine`, you get the OpenType version of Libertine rather than jury-rigged Type 1 fonts:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{mathastext}
```

If you check the output with `pdffonts`, this removes half the fonts used, many of which are 8-bit, and allows you to copy and paste more of the letters.

I also suggested `libertinus`, which loads `unicode-math`.  You write, “but the rest of the math looks funny. See, for example, \mathcal{Z} or the curly braces[....]”

That’s just how the Libertinus Math font looks, so it’s what you get when you do things the easy way.  But, if you don’t like one of its alphabets, you can mix and match.  If you want to change the `\mathcal` alphabet to something more like what you had before, you can do that by adding, after `libertinus`,

```
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}
```

Or you might prefer

```
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase, StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
```

If you want to match the appearance of the original more closely, using only OpenType fonts, you want to load your alphabets individually instead of by package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range={up,it,bfup,bfit,sfup,sfit,bfsfup,bfsfit,tt}]{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\begin{equation*}
  x = y + \sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}} \beta_z
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  x = \argmin_{y \in Y} \bigg \{ f(y) + \frac{1}{g(y) - h(y)} \bigg\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: OpenTYpe Font Sample]

## Original answer

To load the Type 1 font instead, even on XeTeX or LuaTeX, use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
```

Since you’re using XeTeX, consider the `libertinus` package instead of `libertine` and `\newtxmath`.  This loads `unicode-math` with the Libertinus Math font.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The solutions you suggest do not seem to work for me. I will make an edit to my original post to explain better.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini It needed one extra line.

Comment: Yes! That fixes it. Great!

Comment: Using T1-encoding with xetex is not a good idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i did suggest one alternative. Others include: `mathspec`, `mathastext`, playing around with `\operator@font`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` doesn't work either, because then it tries to load an OT1 version of Libertine, for the operator font, which doesn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Using T1-encoding with xelatex is not a good idea. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470987/2388.

Changing the order works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

This is some text. arg min

\begin{equation*}
  x = y + \sum_{z \in \mathcal{Z}} \beta_z
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  x = \argmin_{y \in Y} \bigg \{ f(y) + \frac{1}{g(y) - h(y)} \bigg\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you get an error, show your log-file.

Comment: +1, But I'll edit my answer to fix some of the problems he ran into.