# DeclareMathOperator not displayed in math font with Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-operators, eulervm

I am writing a Beamer presentation using pdfLaTeX for the backend.
I want to use Lato for the text and `eulervm` for the math font.
However my operator Re is not displayed with the math font in the equations:

[image: example]

I don't think this is a duplicate of [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497846/declaremathoperator-does-not-respect-math-font) since I am not using XeTeX.
Regardless, is that expected since I didn't pick a math font that blends beautifully with the text font?
Otherwise, how can I sort this problem? I tried using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` without effect.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Rey}{Re}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{In block}
    \begin{equation*}
      x + y = z
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
      \Rey = 1
    \end{equation*}
    In text \(\Rey = 1\)
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Math operators are done in the roman style, whereas euler is an italic style.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes eulervm also have upright parts normally. The beamer math setup is imo incomplete. Try a normal beamer doc with no extea font setup, explain why mathrm is not set to mathsf by default. Mathrm gives serifs in a setup where both text and math is sans serif. I've started using the sansserifmath package (I think that is the name and I think it gives a better  default math setup for beamer, including setting mathrm to mathsf by default)

Comment: As Mico mentioned in their deleted answer you probably need the professionalfonts setup when you change the fonts used by beamer.

Comment: I mentioned I tried \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} @daleif unless you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\Rey` is supposed to represent the Reynolds number, what about something like `\mathinner{\mathnormal{R\mkern -1mu e}}`? The `\mkern -1mu` ensures this doesn't look like a product between `R` and `e`. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this, but since these glyphs come from a math font, I'm not sure. The `\mathinner` ensures there is some space around the whole, as happens when one uses `\left` and `\right`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\newcommand*{\Rey}{\mathinner{\mathnormal{R\mkern -1mu e}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{In block}
    \begin{equation*}
      x + y = z
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
      \Rey = 1
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
      x\Rey y = 2
    \end{equation*}
    In text: \(\Rey = 1\), $x\Rey y = 2$.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although the workaround solution of @frougon answers the issue, it seems there was another post mentioning that issue [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476516/operator-font-in-beamer-metropolis/478920), which reported a 'more consistent' solution which avoids mingling with the kerning using `\DeclareSymbolFont`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Rey}{Re}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{In block}
    \begin{equation*}
      x + y = z R e
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
      \Rey = 1
    \end{equation*}
    In text \(\Rey = 1\)
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, this would also modify how `\sin` or `\log` appear.

Comment: True! I've just checked on my minimal example.