# luatex: get straight quotation and non-unicode \dots without T1

Tags: luatex, unicode, font-encodings, ellipsis

As [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470976/are-there-cases-where-fontenc-luatex-or-xetex-cause-problems/553893) discusses, `lualatex` has some problems with T1 fontenc.

On the other hand, without T1 fontenc

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
"\dots"
``\ldots''
\end{document}
```

`lualatex` uses the "horizontal ellipsis" character of unicode for `\dots` and the "right double quotation mark" character of unicode for the `"` input.  Neither of them is optimal: The unicode ellipsis character is often too narrow and you sometimes want the straight double quotation symbol.  (If I want the proper closing double quotation mark, I would write `''` or use `\enquote{}`, thank you very much.)

So, how does one redefine `\dots` (and `\ldots`) and `"` without using T1 fontenc?

(Why do I want to use `"` ?  Because I'm quoting a lot of other people's text copy-n-pasting from email.  I want to minimize editing the quoted text.)

**EDIT: Solution to the `\ldots` problem:** `\usepackage{ellipsis}`.

Apparently, the `ellipsis` package has to be loaded *after* the `hyperref` package. Perhaps `hyperref` redifines `\dots` to use the unicode ellipsis. Strangely, this redefinition doesn't happen with `pdflatex`, with or without T1 fontenc. Nor does it happen with `lualatex` with T1 fontenc.(That's why it was so hard to figure out what was going on.)

Comment: you can `\renewcommand\ldots{.\kern.3em.\kern.3em.}` or whatever spacing you would like.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand one of your objectives: You'd like all instances of "..." be replaced automatically by ``...''. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ryo I don't understand your remark about the ellipsis package. That package in LuaLaTeX replaces `\dots` with a more traditional definition. Therefore you certainly can change the width that way and it seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger  You are right! There must be something wrong in my test case.  I'll figure out what's causing `\ldots` to be substituted with the unicode ellipsis and fix my original posting.

Comment: @Mico No. I don't want the `\dots` command to produce the unicode character "horizontal ellipsis".