Can't get libertine to work with newtxmath in lualatex and have PDF/A compliance
I am desperately trying to use libertine font together with newtxmath in lualatex and found two solutions which are equally bad for different reasons. Here is the document:
\pdfvariable minorversion=5
\begin{filecontents*}{main.xmpdata}
\Author{Author name}
\Title{Thesis title}
    \Language{English}
    \Keywords{Physics}
    \Date{2024-01-01}
    \PublicationType{book}
    \Source{}
    \Doi{}
    \URLlink{}
    \end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
% Various includes

% FONT
\usepackage[semibold,type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a-3u]{pdfx}
% More includes

\begin{document}
\end{document}

This produces beautiful text and perfect math without errors BUT the created PDF cannot be made to be PDF/A-compliant because of missing unicode mappings and what not. I guess fontenc may just be too old to support PDF/A compliance with pdfx:

Solution 2 is
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{Libertinus Math}

While I find this math font a bit janky here and there, it may be acceptable overall BUT it is also very broken (despite being "newer"?). Specifically, underbraces are broken:

The line with "{z" should obviously be an underbrace. Math errors like these and missing characters (italic upper case greek and the like) also lead to PDF/A-compliance failure.
My question is: What is the correct way for using libertine font together with newtxmath in a modern way? If there is none, can you recommend a math font that is not broken and has a similar appearance?
Thank you!
I am using TexLive 2023 and luatex 1.17.0

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

well you shouldn't use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with lualatex. Beside this: show a small but complete example that can be used to test the pdf/A problems.

an empty document that produces no output is not an example.

After spending hours on debugging I began using fontenc out of desperation. Ok, I will work out minimal examples

I fount out that my fontenc solution does work if I do not include matplotlib plots that have been generated with newtxmath and fontenc.... I don't even know how to ask in this case :( Using fontspec in matplotlib works, but the font then differs from the math in the thesis

Therefore, as I have to use embedded pdf documents that are not PDF/A compliant I need to give up here. No PDF/A compliance is possible in my case. Of course, the underbrace error is still bizarre, but I will probably stick with solution 1 which at least produces a good looking document

you should not use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with lualatex. The encoding is wrong. Try to write e.g. grüße and look what happens. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470987/2388

Of course you are right, and I know it ;) For now I will use Grü\ss{}e as a workaround, which, by some miracle, renders correctly. If I wanted to use fontspec everywhere, I would need to give up my preference for newtxmath, as it cannot render underbraces. Of course, I am not the first one to notice this issue, and this might warrant a separate question.

I found a solution that uses fontspec and newtxmath (this is why underbrace works now I guess) and libertine and almost-PDF/A-compliance and everything seems to work, except for \mathbb{1}, for which I will surely find a solution. unicode-math cannot be combined with these packages it seems, which could be the reason that pdfx generates 100 warnings. Of course, perfect PDF/A-compliance cannot be achieved in the end if the logo of your university is not PDF/A compliant in the first place (duh), therefore almost-PDF/A-compliance must suffice for the Uni library.
\pdfvariable minorversion=5
\begin{filecontents*}{main.xmpdata}
\Author{Author name}
\Title{Thesis title}
    \Language{English}
    \Keywords{Physics}
    \Date{2024-01-01}
    \PublicationType{book}
    \Source{}
    \Doi{}
    \URLlink{}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    fontsize=12pt,
    twoside,
    BCOR=15mm,
    bibliography=totoc,
    headings=optiontotocandhead,
    captions=tableheading,
    titlepage=firstiscover,
    numbers=noeenddot
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{Fira Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\usepackage[a-3u]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{
    english, unicode,pdfusetitle, pdfencoding=auto
}

\title{Libertine}
\author{My Name}
\date{June 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro $\boldsymbol{B^0\to J\!/\!\psi\pi^0}$}
\section{Math $\boldsymbol{\alpha^2+A^2+n^2}$}
\subsection{Math $\boldsymbol{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}$}

\noindent This is the introduction. 

\noindent Das ist Deutsch ßẞÄäÖöÜü. Schöne Grüße an alle!

\noindent\textit{Actually, this is wrong}

\noindent\textbf{Now I am yelling!} 

\noindent\textbf{\textit{I am yelling in Italy!}}

\noindent\texttt{This is typewriter text.}

\begin{align*}
    \int_0^\infty x^2 &= \infty &  \prod_k \sum^\infty x^2 &= \infty\\
    B^0\to J\!/\!\psi \pi^0 &= 0 &  \underbrace{\frac{V_{us}V_{ud}}{\sqrt{3}}}_{K} &= \pi^2-\zeta^2\\
    \Im{\lambda}&=S &  \Re{5}&=5\\
    \mathbb{1RCN} &= 12 &  \boldsymbol{M}^2&=\boldsymbol{\Gamma}\\
    \boldsymbol{B^0\to J\!/\!\psi \pi^0} &= 0 &  \boldsymbol{M}^2&=\boldsymbol{\Gamma}
\end{align*}

\chapter{The origin of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The section origin of $\alpha$}
\subsection{The subsection origin of $\alpha$}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


This produces

If someone knows how to get rid of these warnings, possibly by including unicode-math somehow, please let me know!


Off topic: mathtools loads amsmath, so it's not necessary to load them both.

thanks, I removed the amsmath import
