How do I get the German letter Eszett (ß) to print in LuaLaTex when using the fbb font package?
I'm using LuaLaTeX (on a Mac running Texifier) and the fbb font package.  I can enter an eszett (ß) by typing option+s, but it renders as SS instead of as ß. The LaTeX shortcut of \ss{} works, but I'd rather not have to type it if I don't have to. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
My mwe:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}, margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[p,osf]{fbb}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

groß % this renders as groSS - not what I want

gro\ss{} % this renders as groß - this is what I want

\end{document}


Weird. It works correctly with pdflatex but not the unicode engines

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Untested but I bet that the fbb package sets t1 encoding and so is not suited for lualatex.see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470987/2388

Very good MWE! I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your query to highlight the fact that the 'fbb' package is used. Feel free to revert.

(I revised my answer thoroughly after reading the user guide of the fbb font package more closely.)
The following piece of information is somewhat buried in the user guide of the fbb package: Under LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, the correct way to load the fbb font is not
\usepackage{fbb}

but, rather,
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{fbb}

The LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX equivalent of \usepackage[p,osf]{fbb} is
\setmainfont{fbb}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]

Sometimes, it pays to read the manual...

Aside: Michael Sharpe's fbb package uses a font face called bembo, which is based on the OpenType Cardo font face. Cardo has a very large set of glyphs and was specifically designed for the needs of classicists, Biblical scholars, medievalists, and linguists. According to the CTAN page of the fbb package, bembo "adds Bold Italic, small caps in all styles, six figure choices in all styles, updated kerning tables, added figure tables, and corrected f-ligatures" to Cardo.
More about the Cardo font face: It is based, in turn, on Monotype's Bembo font face of the late 1920s. Cardo has been around for well more than a decade by now. It was designed by David Perry, and its 2011 version may still be downloaded from this site. At present, Google Fonts also distributes Cardo, and you may prefer to use this link to download it.
Incidentally, the names "Cardo" and "Bembo" both go back more than 500 years. In 1495 or 1496, the type designer Aldus Manutius, who had moved to Venice in 1494 and created the Aldine Press, and the punchcutter Francesco Griffo created a font face for the poet and humanist Pietro Bembo, a member of Venice's prominent Bembo family, who would later become a cardinal and who, in 1496, published a book entitled "De Ætna ad Angelum Chabrielem Liber" (English: "A book from Etna [the volcano in Sicily] to the Archangel Gabriel"), "De Aetna" for short. The thoughts the good cardinal expressed in "De Aetna" turned out not to have a lasting influence. In contrast, the font face employed in "De Aetna" had a huge and  long lasting impact on typography. This font face would eventually form the basis for Monotype's celebrated Bembo font face.


\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}, margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[p,osf]{fbb}
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{fbb}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]
\fi

\begin{document}

groß % this now renders correctly under LuaLaTeX

gro\ss{} % this also renders as expected

0123456789 000111000
\end{document}


The English translation of the title has 'on Etna' instead of 'from Etna'.

Williams in his book 'Pietro Bembo on Etna: The Ascent of a Venetian Humanist' (2017) translates the original title 'PETRI BEMBI DE AETNA AD ANGELUM CHABRIELEM LIBER' as 'PIETRO BEMBO'S ON ETNA FOR ANGELO GABRIELE'. So the Latin 'de' in its meaning of 'about', conventional in book titles (De rerum natura, De bello Gallico, De revolutionibus orbium coelestium). The English translation of De Aetna by Betty Radice (1969) has simply 'Etna', which would be off if the emphasis is on locational meaning. Same for the German translation by Gerd von der Gönna (2015), 'Der Ätna".

@MarkvanAtten - Latin locutions can be ambiguous, i.e., they can have more than one meaning; this is frequently deliberate, not accidental. Williams' translation choice focuses heavily on the immediate context, e.g., the existence of a person named Angelo Gabriele who traveled with Pietro Bembo to Sicily, or the fact that Pietro Bembo climbed Mount Etna at some point during his stay in Sicily. Unfortunately, this direct or immediate translation approach fails to capture the title's second, deeply spiritual meaning. It's the latter meaning that I tried to convey in my translation.

If you really need LuaLaTeX, you can get away using luainputenc.
The problem is that when LuaTeX sees ß it tries to typeset the character at slot U+00DF in the font, which for fbb (that's T1 encoded) happens to contain the single glyph “SS” (which used to be the uppercase counterpart of ß). Other German characters do not show problems, because T1 places them in the same position as Latin-1, which is how Unicode starts from.
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}, margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[p,osf]{fbb}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

groß % this renders as groSS - not what I want

gro\ss{} % this renders as groß - this is what I want

\end{document}


However, with LuaLaTeX it's better to use OpenType fonts.

+1 for "However, with LuaLaTeX it's better to use OpenType fonts.". :-)
