# How to solve "compile have difficult understand \tikz@texfont -> amsfonts"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, flow-charts

My flow chart keeps having the problem below:

I think because I am using a font: `amsfonts`

```
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,
nodes={on chain,draw,minimum height=1.7em,inner xsep=1ex,
    equal size,rounded corners,join,font=\amsfonts},
```

However, I want my flow char having the same font as my text.
I am not sure what is my font size here. I assume is `amsfonts`

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem, url}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} %for table multirow


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,
    nodes={on chain,draw,minimum height=1.7em,inner xsep=1ex,
        equal size,rounded corners,join,font=\amsfonts},
    every join/.style={-{Triangle[length=2mm,width=4mm]},line width=1.5mm,
        gray!50,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm}]
 \node{Sample 1}; 
 \node{Sample 1}; 
  \node{Sample 1}; 
   \node{Sample 1}; 
    \node{Sample 1}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Testing Sample 1 Sample 1.}
\label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop the key `font=\amsfonts`. This is not a valid command. The font size will be the one of the ambient text unless you change it, so you do not need to add a key for that, let alone `font=\amsfonts`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks! It works. If I want to use a specific `font` type, is it possible? Beside `font=\sffamily`?

Comment: Are there font options? I bet there are. Just look e.g. at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426279/194703). There are many. `\sffamily` is not a font but a family, you could also use `font=\ttfamily`. You can change the font weight with `font=\bfseries` and you can combine all those.