# How to remove the white spaces from the beginning of Abstract title?

Tags: pdftex, abstract

I am using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}` for my document. I want to remove the small space just before the "Abstract." title. How to remove that small space? I want to strat the "Abstract." title just like "Keywords" without any white spaces at begining.

Here is the **screenshot**:
[image]

I am using the following in my **preamble**:

```latex
\usepackage[runin]{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text
\abslabeldelim{.}
```

In the `main.tex` I am using:

```latex
\begin{abstract}
    \input{sections/abstract}

    \noindent\textbf{Keywords.} \pdfKeywords\par
\end{abstract}
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\abstitleskip` setting it to `-\parindent`.

You also want to apply `\small` to the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[runin]{abstract} % Allows abstract customization

\usepackage{lipsum}% mock text

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\small\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text
\abslabeldelim{.}
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-\parindent}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Sigma}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\smallskip

\noindent\textbf{Keywords.} Pizza, without, pineapple.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

A small skip between the abstract and the keywords seems necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do think about this solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\begin{document}


\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm} %By setting the dimensions you can choose how small or wide the abstract text should appear

\fontsize{12}{9}\selectfont \textbf{Abstract.} \lipsum[1] %or any other text
%\fontsize: first number changes the size of the font and the second number changes the leading. Set it to the desired numbers.

\noindent \textbf{Keywords.} First keyword, second keyword, third keyword,...
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{Introduction}
\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont \fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont %change the font code as detailed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426279/fontfamily-selectfont-does-not-work-with-xelatex-engine, for the rest see above
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution could be the last resort for me. This solution doesn't keep the fontsize and fontfamily in the abstract. These are set by `\abstractnamefont`. Is there any solution using \usepackage{abstract}?

Comment: I changed parts of the code, should now fit better to your needs...