# Renew Command for a footnote

Tags: footnotes

I would need to change the font of all footnotes in a document; the brute force way would be to change the font in each and everyone of them, except that they are a few dozen.

I thought I could use `\renewcommand` in the preamble, but I do not seem to have it work. How can I have that each time I have a footnote it is in italics, without having to write

```
\footnote{\textit{blahblah}}
```

I know the question is trivial for most of you, but I seem to get something wrong
Thanks!
francesco

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \renewcommand{\footnote}{\footnote{\italics}}
```

Comment: It can be done, but we would need to know what packages you are loading to know what changes they do to the internals of the `\footnote` command. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document for us to check.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4779/35864

Comment: Note that [`amssymb` already loads `amsfonts`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32100/35864), so it is enough to load `amssymb`. Furthermore this is not an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it might be enough to understand you question in this instance, but in general it might not be enough and it is good practice to post fully working examples.

Comment: Edited with the MWE (which does not work :)  I also tried as @moewe suggests \addtokomafont{footnote}{\textit}, but it gives an error. Do I need to load a package?

Comment: Does `\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand*{\footnotelayout}{\itshape}` as suggested in the linked answer work for you? `\addtokomafont` is a command of the KOMA script bundle, so it is not available in the standard classes.

Comment: You can use the KOMA command if you load `scrextend` and let it take over the footnotes: `\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\itshape}`.

Comment: \footmisc indeed worked! for some reason, the complicated preamble to the book I am writing prevented footnotes to be typeset in \librebaskerville. So I added  \usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\renewcommand*{\footnotelayout}{\librebaskerville} and now it works! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want the footnote mark in italics as well, so it's just a matter of finding the best way where to set `\itshape` and the start of the call of `\@makefntext` seems the place.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\rule}{\itshape\rule}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\textheight=2cm % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{This footnote is in italics}
Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]